# Find if relation is partial / total ordered

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, order-theory

These are two problems of the Velleman's `How to prove` book in which it has been asked to find if $R$ is an partial order or/and an total order:

$R1 = \{(x,y) \in A \times A \mid \text{the word $y$ occurs at least as late in alphabetical order as the word $x$} \}$

$R2 = \{(x,y) \in A \times A \mid \text{the first letter of the word $y$ occurs at least as late in the alphabet as the first letter of the word $x$}\}$

where $A$ is the set of all words of English.

Now I conclude that $R1$ is not a total order because $(haskell, go) \notin R$. Also for the set $R2$ it is not a partial order because of an element like $(aba, aa)$. But the solution presented [here](http://technotes-himanshu.blogspot.in/2010/06/how-to-prove-it-ch4-sec44ordering.html) claims otherwise. So am I missing something here ?

Comment: Which examples are these two?

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. What example are you speaking about ?

Comment: I was looking at the link.  It has answers to three exercises, and I was guessing that two of these were the solutions to your problems.  I couldn't tell which was which.

Comment: @RossMillikan Problem 2 - subpart (a) and (b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A total order requires that either $(x,y)$ or $(y,x)$ be part of the relation.  It is similar to $\le$ on the naturals.  We don't have $2 \le 1$, but we do have $1 \le 2$, so it could be (and is) a total order.  Similarly, your example (haskell,go) is not part of the order, but (go,haskell) is. For the second, a partial order has to be transitive and antisymmetric. In this case, both (aa,aba) and (aba,aa) are part of the relation.  Since aa $\neq$ aba, it is not antisymmetric and this is not a partial order.

Comment: Oh yes it should have been (go, haskell). Thanks for correcting it.